# Determining the element in an XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document that I'm trying to parse.  Here is what it looks like (just the format here, no data):

```
 <objectdata>
   <title></title>
     <assignableunit>    
       <other></other>    
       <other></other>    
       <text></text>    
       <name></name>
     </assignableunit>    
 </objectdata>
```

What I had planned on doing was to loop through the xml document and act on each element.  For instance, if the element is `<assignableunit>`  I'd call code to act on that particular element.  If the element is `<text>`, I'd call code to act on that.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("Items.xml");
foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Descendants("objectdata"))
{   
  //if element is <assignableunit>...
  //if element is <other>...
  //if element is <name>...
  //etc... 
}
```

I thought maybe using a switch/case to determine the type of element would work, but I can't figure out how to determine the type of element.  Can someone offer a point in the right direction?  I haven't dealt much at all with XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using `XElement` instead of `XmlNode` or `XmlElement` which a lot of tutorials/examples use, you need to use `Name` property which is a `XName` object. The non-linq objects have these broken out into separate properties such as `Name` and `LocalName` while `XElement` has this combined using the `XName` type.

```
if (element.Name.LocalName == "title")
{
   // Do something with title data
}
else if (element.Name.LocalName == "assignableunit")
{
  // Do something with assignableunit data
  foreach(XElement childElement in element.Descendents())
  {
      if (childElement.Name.LocalName == "other")
      {

      }
      else if (........)
      {
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`element.Name.LocalName` should get you what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.localname(v=vs.110).aspx